# server domain subdomain cpanel

Tags: dns, subdomain, cpanel, nameservers

I have a website hosted at hostgator.com, I will call it

www.orig-domain.com

I just opened up a new account at hostgator.com I will call it

www.new-domain.com

I don't want to set up a new website for www.new-domain.com but just want to use the server power to help www.orig-domain.com (since the dedicated plans are expensive)

is it possible to allocate "sub.orig-domain.com" name to the server for "www.new-domain.com"

it would be great to know if this is even possible then I can stop researching.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Just add a CNAME record in your DNS of `orig-domain.com` to go from `sub.orig-domain.com` to `www.new-domain.com`